# Edit a database record through the Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, console

Example scenario: I'm on my mac's Terminal inside the Rails console and have just entered the following database record with a misspelling in one of the fields:

```
irb(main):019:0> Meme.create(:category => 'funny', :title => 'Balloon frihgtens cat')
```

Q: Using the Rails console, how can I fix that record to have the correct spelling of "frihgtens"?

Comment: Load the meme and update the attribute. Any basic AR tutorial/guide will discuss the two method calls this requires. I suppose you could do it in one as well.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Step 1. Find the record.

Step 2. Edit the record.

Assuming `title` is unique, the following should work:

```
> m = Meme.where(:title => 'Balloon frihgtens cat').first
> m.title = 'Balloon frightens cat'
> m.save
```

Read up http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html to learn more about using active record.

Comment: Thanks, Prakash! Your answer worked like a charm. And thanks also for the link to active record querying. I'm learning Ruby so this will probably be very helpful.

Comment: Now I'm eager to find this meme with the baloon-frihgtened cat

Answer (score 4):

- **Find the record**

  You can use find or where to get the record
  open up the rails console run the command Meme.all spot the record you     want to update, get the ID of that record.(Lets say ID is 5)

  @meme = Meme.find(5) or @meme = Meme.where(:title => "Balloon frihgtens cat")
- **Update the record**

  @meme.update(:title => "Balloon frightens cat")

Answer (score 4):

Type the following inside `rails console` not `irb`

```
meme = Meme.find_by(:title => 'Balloon frihgtens cat')
meme.title = 'Ballon frightens cat'
meme.save
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

```
Client.find(3).update(key: "value")
```

Client ---> table,
find(3) ---> which record,
key ---> which column,
value ---> what changes u want to update

Answer (score 3):

please try to following code:

```
meme = Meme.where(:title => 'Balloon frihgtens cat').first
meme.update_attribute(:title, 'Balloon frightens cat')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do 3 things:
1 Find the record:

```
x = Record.where(title: "whatever")
```

Update it:

```
x.title = "new title"
```

Save it:

```
x.save
```

And do not use irb use rails console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this oneliner:

```rb
Company.update 1, name: 'Rebranded', score: 99
```

where first parameter is id.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `irb`, not `rails console`.

`AppledeMac-mini-2% rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
2.1.6 :001 >`

A: If something wrong, you will get a error report. But this can not check the spiling of the value. Like this:

`2.1.6 :003 > Menu.create(naame: 'aa')
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'naame' for Menu.`